# Rendering returned fetched JSON data in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I am new to Backbone.js so please bear with me.

I have the following code that correctly fetches JSON onSearchClicked. I can see the JSON in the console view. I would like to render the retrieved responseJSON to a view or pass the data through an existing model (under car_view.js) - so I can view on a HTML page. How can I do this?

Any help much appreciated.

```
view.js
--------------
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',
  ranking: 0,

  events:{
    'click .search-button': 'onSearchClicked'
  },

  onSearchClicked : function(){
     var searchString = $('.search-field input').val();
     $('#gallery ul').empty();
     var search = new carCollection([], {query: searchString});
     search.fetch( {success: this.searchResults.bind(this) });
     console.log(search.fetch());
  },

},

search_collection.js
--------------

var Backbone = require('backbone');
var BurgerModel = require('../models/car');

var CarCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:CarModel,
    initialize : function(models, options){
        this.query = options.query;
    },
    url: function(){
        return "/api/cars?name="+this.query;
    }
});

module.exports = CarCollection;

car_view.js
--------------

carCard: function( burger ){
    var carView = new CarView({
      model: car
    });

    this.$el.append( carView.el );
},
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo - Make 'C' capital in this line:

```
var search = new carCollection([], {query: searchString});
```

I am not going to provide the working code but I can provide you steps:

1. Please create a new class CarList which should have a reference to CarCollection
2. When User enters search query, a method of CarList should be invoked in which you should call fetch of collection
3. In success callback of fetch invoke a method `renderCars`
4. Inside `renderCars` For each search result create an instance of CarView and render it in an element.

Hope this is what you want. If you are looking for exact code, then nobody is going to help you on SO!!